# Python selenium save screenshot in newly created folder

Tags: python, function, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to create a folder where screenshots will be saved when a test fails, it would be great if the folder is only created when there is a test failure.

This is currently not working, it is not saving the screenshot inside the folder:

```
try:
    os.makedirs('./screenshots')
except OSError:
    pass

def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
        driver.save_screenshot('screenshots/screenie.png')
    return True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `save_screenshot()` call is unreacheable, the function returns before making a screenshot. The fixed version:

```
def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.save_screenshot('screenshots/screenie.png')
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't save the screenshot and how can I only create the folder on test failure?

Comment: @programiss ok, for starters, please remove the try/except block and just call `os.makedirs('./screenshots')` - let's see if it throws an exception.

Comment: I tried that and it said there was a directory already created, after deleting it..it created the folder but no screenshot inside

Comment: @programiss try this `driver.save_screenshot(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'screenshots', 'screenie.png'))`. Don't forget to import `os`.

Comment: @programiss interesting, it is working for me, and without the `os.path()` magic it also worked. Let's debug more. First of all, could you omit the `./` here and try `os.makedirs('screenshots')`? Also, add `print` before the `save_screenshot()` call: `print driver.save_screenshot()`. What is printed? Thanks.

Comment: It didn't print anything

Comment: @programiss then, `NoSuchElementException` was not thrown. Check if `save_screenshot()` was actually executed.

Comment: You're right save_screenshot() is not being executed idk why. Before it was saving the screenshot inside of the current directory but not inside the folder

Answer (score 0):

```
class saveScreen:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image_no = 0
    def save(self,driver):
        self.image_no+=1
        driver.save_screenshot("./screenshots/images"+str(self.image_no)+".png")

obj = saveScreen()
obj.save(driver)
```